# How to run a SQL file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have multiple `.sql` files which might consists of multiple Alter table statements or view definitions or `plsql` function definitions. I want to apply complete `sql` file on PostgreSQL DB. It should be something similar like

```
psql -h "HostName" -p "Port" -U "userName" -d "pwd" -f "Sql file location"
```

I have tried doing `PG.connect.execute` and that way I need to load the file and execute each statement separately. Is there a way I can execute entire `sql` file in Ruby?

Answer (score 3):

There are two APIs for communicating with a PostgreSQL database, and both are
available as gems. The  pg gem provides a pure Ruby binding to Postgres.

Exemple:
This code assumes you’re accessing the database through TCP/IP on port 5432 of
your local machine:

```
gem 'pg'
require 'pg'
 def with_db
   db = PG.connect(
     dbname: 'dbname',
     user: 'user',
     password: 'password'
   )
   begin
      yield db
   ensure
      db.close
   end
 end

sql = File.open('path/to/your_sql.sql', 'rb') { |file| file.read }
with_db do |db|
  begin
    db.exec(sql)
  rescue PG::Error
     #####
  end
end
```

For more information [check this](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg)