# Allow users to upload a .db file within a rails app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want a user to be able to select a .db file from their file browser. Then I need to be able to read the contents of that .db file from my rails app.

When I use the normal File.open(**) I am getting a lot of strange characters outputted so I can't read it. I was wondering if there is a way to call on sql from inside the rails app so that I could use sql to open this .db file and then read the contents that way?

Comment: I think you have to save the file somewhere on your server or file storage. After that you should be able to open a db connection to that file and run queries on it. Have you seen this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298692/how-to-run-a-sql-file-in-ruby?answertab=active#tab-top It's for postgres, but I think this could help

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't know the table names if the users are uploading arbitrary .db files. It's really complicated. I don't know if it is even possible

Comment: What is the use case in reality. Since 7 years of programming I have never heard of such a thing :)

Comment: And if you dont know the data structure, then its quite impossible to make queries

Comment: I haven't either! It's because the users are given this zip files that has a .db file within it. That db was encrypted thanks to EST3 ancient software, but I was able to read the bytes and get some of the content. In the end, the encryption made it impossible to read all of it, so it's unfeasible. But it was a fun attempt!